# Using IntellijIDEA and Mercurial VCS - red exclamation point in windows file system - what does it mean?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, mercurial

I'm using IntellijIDEA and Mercurial for version control, and I am new to both. I get the following exclamation icons in my file system at the top level of my projects. I assume it has to do with Mercurial version control, but what exactly does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link appears to partially answer the question:

http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/quick.html

However, the different between the (+), (✓) and (!) and icons are not really explained therein.